# I wanted to change my ecu, will buy used ecu and reprogram on my mercedes c180 w205

Tags: mercedes-benz, electronic-control-module

I wanted to change  my ecu, will buy used ecu and reprogram on my mercedes c180 w205 is that possible? How do I go about it

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish through doing this?

Comment: Its possible but probably easier to send your ecu out and have it cloned over to a replacement.